# jQuery fileUpload will rename the files but not the post value of the file name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I am using the jQuery fileUpload plugin as a file manager. When someone uploads a file with the same file name as an existing file the file name renames to 'name (1).ext' or 'name (2).ext' for the actual file and for what it displays in the UI but the file name value in the POST data does not so the wrong data gets entered into the database and the wrong file gets deleted when the delete script is called later.

Is there a way to update the post data that gets sent to match what is being displayed on the screen?

The demo (here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) doesn't rename but I think that's because it doesn't save the files you upload so it can't detect a conflict.

[image: Screenshot of my form after uploading duplicate file name]

Answer (score 0):

Do not store it with the same name as it is uploaded. Generate names for all uploaded files on the server-side. Why would you need original name anyway?

Comment: I was thinking of that but I still have two sections of code that can't talk to each other and may no run at the exact same time, how would I generate a random (or at least unique) name in a way that both will get the same result?